# Docker - springboot on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2

Just spun an EC2 ubunto on AWS. Installed Docker. Pulled my test springboot image and run it on the host. Can't access the app via browser. When I curl on the host, it does respond with valid http response. Is there a network or firewall that I should be looking at?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-4-157:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ea9879c1b38c        parikshit123/docker-spring-boot:firsttry   "java -jar docker-sp…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp   frosty_sammet
ubuntu@ip-172-31-4-157:~$ curl localhost:8085/test/hello
Hello from Mitalubuntu@ip-172-31-4-157:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out.

By default, AWS Ec2 instances have ALL TCP tranffic (inbound and outbound) blocked. I learned that it has to be g opened. I added security group and it worked. Now I can access the endpoint via browser. Bingo!

Comment: Please note that you don't need to open ALL ports for all traffic. Configure security group using the least privilege required.